# Vim cursor shape depending on current mode

Tags: ssh, vim, macvim

I currently use MacVim for a lot of my editor needs but occasionally I need to edit files remotely over SSH. In MacVim the shape of the cursor varies depending on your current mode, i.e.
`command mode -> block cursor` and `insert mode -> vertical bar cursor`, 
which I find very helpful.

Is there a way to replicate this behavior in a `.vimrc` file, so that it can be used remotely?

Comment: Have you played with the `gcr` (aka `guicursor` setting)?

Comment: @Josef, can you tell me more about `gcr`? How to set it?

Answer (score 9):

Try `:help termcap-cursor-shape`. There are two options there you can set:

1. `&t_SI` - Shape when you enter insert mode.
2. `&t_EI` - Shape when you exit insert mode.

In order for this to work, the Vim you are using must have been compiled with `+cursorshape` feature.

I personally always use gvim, so this was never a problem `:)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately gVim isn't installed on the server I'm accessing.  I did a little searching and it looks like the cursor shape can't be changed in regular Vim.  Oh well.

Comment: @David, as of Vim 7.3 you can change the cursor in regular vim too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488683/how-do-i-change-the-vim-cursor-in-insert-normal-mode/6488717#6488717