# How to change the cursor between Normal and Insert modes in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to know how to change, if possible, the cursor in Vim (in color, shape, etc.) depending on what mode you are in.

I am constantly forgetting that I am not in Insert mode and start typing code, which results in all sorts of crazy things happening. It would be helpful if there was some sort of visual indication on the cursor.

Comment: I suggest you to learn one rule: stopped typing => exit insert mode. Then you will never observe a situation where you forgot that you are not in insert mode.

Comment: @ZyX *except* when you forget to exit the insert mode after having stopped typing :p

Comment: @ZyX that's a fine rule and I have always done that, but visual indicators are still important. Marijuana is legal now and I forget what I'm doing all the time.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

A popular approach to indicate switching to and from Insert mode is
toggling the `cursorline` option, which is responsible for whether
the current screen line is highlighted (see `:help cursorline`):

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * set cursorline
:autocmd InsertLeave * set nocursorline
```

or, alternatively:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave * set cul!
```

Modify the `CursorLine` highlighting group to change the styling
of the cursor line to your liking (see `:help :highlight` and
`:help highlight-groups`).

This approach assumes, of course, that you do not use the cursor
line highlighting in Normal mode.

Comment: I also set cul to higlight bg instead of default underline: hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=black

Comment: Is there a reason this wouldn't work in cygwin's vim? I'm in the editor and entered both set of lines, and  I haven't been able to set any sort of highlighting, beyond the full column or row highligting

Comment: @Tankor:  The `cursorline` option does not depend on any platform-specific capability; it is available on any Vim instance compiled with the `+syntax` feature (which is usually the case).

Comment: Of course, save that to your ~/.vimrc for permanence like zo: `echo 'autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave * set cul!' >>~/.vimrc`

Comment: Correct vim version 7.4 not support variables like `t_SI` so to change cursor I use this two lines.
`set cursorline` and  
`autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave * set cul!`

Answer (score 161):

The following works in xterm, urxvt, and other terminal emulators on Linux; iTerm2 on macOS; Git Bash with ConEmu on Windows; and more (see comments):

```
let &t_SI = "\e[6 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"

" reset the cursor on start (for older versions of vim, usually not required)
augroup myCmds
au!
autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\e[2 q"
augroup END
```

Other options (replace the number after `\e[`):

```
Ps = 0  -> blinking block.
Ps = 1  -> blinking block (default).
Ps = 2  -> steady block.
Ps = 3  -> blinking underline.
Ps = 4  -> steady underline.
Ps = 5  -> blinking bar (xterm).
Ps = 6  -> steady bar (xterm).
```

---

When you use **tmux**, it is important to use it like that (without the `\<Esc>Ptmux;` escape). tmux will keep track of the correct cursor shape when you switch windows/panes.

If it does not work for you, try either to set `TERM=xterm-256color` before starting tmux, or add this to your `.tmux.conf` ([thanks @Steven Lu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488683/how-do-i-change-the-vim-cursor-in-insert-normal-mode/6489348#comment102725650_42118416)):

```
set -ga terminal-overrides ',*:Ss=\E[%p1%d q:Se=\E[2 q'
```

Comment: Works great in alacritty now

Comment: Works perfect in xfce4-terminal

Comment: @Charles About why it does not work in putty, see this: https://superuser.com/questions/304318/over-windows-terminal-change-cursor-width-or-color-in-vim-depending-on-mode

Comment: Works great with Kitty. However the 'optional reset cursor on start' code produces this jumble of characters in the command section at the bottom whenever you start vim. 

^[[2;2R^[[>1;4000;13c^[]10;rgb:dddd/eeee/dddd^[\^[]11;rgb:1c1c/1c1c/1c1c^[\

Any fixes for this?

Comment: @MartianTomatoes Append `autocmd VimEnter * redraw!` to the `augroup`.

Comment: Using iterm and VIM8 there's a delay when going back to normal mode from insert. The cursor also remains after exiting vim.

Comment: Works on Linux (TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color) without tmux but not inside tmux :(

Comment: I realized this actually totally does not work for me in any terminal within tmux, on Ubuntu or macOS Mojave. I have been using the other answer with the Ptmux; escape, which makes it function transparently for tmux, and is not ideal.

Comment: My Update: working finally with `set -ga terminal-overrides ',*:Ss=\E[%p1%d q:Se=\E[2 q'` in my tmux configuration. Apparently if you use `set` for `terminal-overrides` without `-a`, it will override the setting, which already has this there by default.

Comment: Works perfectly on Tilix

Comment: the solution has a significant delay of changing shape from insert mode to normal mode on simple terminal (suckless st)

Comment: What should happen if we do not reset the cursor on start?

Comment: The tmux bit is very enlightening! Thanks a lot!

Comment: and for GNU screen you need to wrap it in `\eP` teriminal code `\e\\ ` .

Comment: Thanks. I have added these lines to my /etc/vim/vimrc file

Comment: works great in Spacevim running on ITerm (MacOS)

Answer (score 33):

Not sure if anyone else is facing a delay after hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to go back to normal mode to show the block cursor but if so, this is the way I fix it too.

Actually I'm using iTerm2 and using Vim inside my terminal on macOS. And when entering to insert mode, the cursor still being a block and is kind of confusing when you are at insert mode or normal mode.

I wanted to show a thin line as cursor when in insert mode and back to block when in normal mode as MacVim does. And to do so it's pretty simple, just added this to my `.vimrc` file as [described here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes):

```sh
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

[image]

But as you can see there was a delay when hitting `ESC` to exit insert mode back to normal mode and show the block as cursor again. So to fix it I found this:

```sh
set ttimeout
set ttimeoutlen=1
set ttyfast
```

And now it works pretty fine as you can see:

[image: fix delay going back to block as cursor]

I hope it could help any one else!

Comment: The mode change lag was bugging me for so long. Thank you!

Comment: @leedreit same for me until I found this workaround!

Answer (score 20):

If you are using **tmux** and **iTerm2** on **macOS**,
the following changes the cursor from a block to a cursor and highlights the current line

```
if exists('$TMUX')
  let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7\<Esc>\\"
  let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7\<Esc>\\"
else
  let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
  let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
endif
:autocmd InsertEnter * set cul
:autocmd InsertLeave * set nocul
```

credit: https://gist.github.com/andyfowler/1195581

Comment: Note this is *specific to iTerm*. Since the standard ones actually also work but also work in all the other supporting terminals, this is probably the wrong answer. Look here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118416/340947

Comment: @StevenLu actually the one in your suggested answer didn't work for iTerm2 (Mac), while this one worked.  This stuff is more fiddly than you might expect.

Comment: This cursor stuff is definitely one of the fiddlier things out there. I just realized that don't even think I have a proper setup, as tmux does not appear to be performing cursor state tracking which some answers indicate is a possibility. I was plenty happy enough just to get vim to handle setting the cursor to a line on insert mode.

Comment: I figured this stuff out. The solution is to tweak tmux to properly handle it, and it can be non-obvious. What I needed to do was ensure that my tmux config's `terminal-overrides` was only being appended to, so it didn't clobber the `,*:Ss=\E[%p1%d q:Se=\E[2 q` part of `terminal-overrides`. so my config looks like `set -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color-italic:Tc"` (to set the 24-bit color enabling without trampling cursor styles Ss/Se.

Answer (score 13):

To change the shape of the cursor in different modes, you can add the following into your `.vimrc` file.

For the GNOME Terminal (version 2.26):

```
if has("autocmd")
  au InsertEnter * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape ibeam"
  au InsertLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape block"
  au VimLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape ibeam"
endif
```

If you use more than one profile in GNOME Terminal, you might have to adapt this to your profiles.

For Konsole in KDE4:

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

This works with multiple tabs and windows.

See also: “[Change cursor shape in different modes](https://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes)” on [Vim Tips Wiki](https://vim.wikia.com/).

Comment: I primarily use vim in tmux over ssh with putty. Is there a more universal option?

Comment: Changing gnome-terminal's settings via a gconftool-2 command is a very bad idea. It does not only influence the terminal where your vim is running, but also all other current and future gnome-terminal tabs of the same profile.

Comment: this works for konsole, thank you. But one issue is that exiting insert mode is slooow, not sure why

Comment: @HoangTran use `set ttimeoutlen=0`

Comment: how to apply this to all profiles. Eg I have One light and Foxnight profiles - When I use Default it only works for Foxnight profile.

Answer (score 11):

You may try the [Terminus Vim plugin](https://github.com/wincent/terminus):

> In insert mode, the cursor shape changes to a thin vertical bar. In replace mode, it changes to an underline. On returning to normal mode, it reverts to the standard "block" shape.

Comment: This seems like the most sensible solution.  There should be a :set for this directly in VIM, standard.

Comment: Requirements: gnome-terminal (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal) and other terminals using the VTE library (https://github.com/GNOME/vte): Partially supported (for example, supports cursor shape changes but not focus reporting). In my case (gnome-terminal 3.6.2) it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 10):

I find it useful to only have the cursor blinking in Insert mode and keep it static in other modes.

```
set guicursor+=n-v-c:blinkon0
```

Comment: This solution causes a cursor to blink in all modes.

Answer (score 9):

According to this [post](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes) on "[Vim Tips WiKi](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki)":

"To change the shape of the cursor in different modes, you can add the following into your vimrc:"

"For Terminal on macOS"

```
"Mode Settings

let &t_SI.="\e[5 q" "SI = INSERT mode
let &t_SR.="\e[4 q" "SR = REPLACE mode
let &t_EI.="\e[1 q" "EI = NORMAL mode (ELSE)

"Cursor settings:

"  1 -> blinking block
"  2 -> solid block 
"  3 -> blinking underscore
"  4 -> solid underscore
"  5 -> blinking vertical bar
"  6 -> solid vertical bar
```

Scripts for other OS are also included in that post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a modern version of `nvim` and you wanted to achieve this, you can avoid some of these fancy workarounds listed above.

The below settings will switch from block cursor in normal mode, to underline cursor in replace to line cursor in insert.

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
set -ga terminal-overrides '*:Ss=\E[%p1%d q:Se=\E[ q',w
```

```
" ~/.vimrc
" Sets cursor styles
" Block in normal, line in insert, underline in replace
set guicursor=n-v-c-sm:block,i-ci-ve:ver25-Cursor,r-cr-o:hor20
```

I managed to get this working with the following settings pulled from these two sources.

[tui-cursor-shape](https://neovim.io/doc/user/term.html#tui-cursor-shape)

[guicursor](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'guicursor')

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this adds much to the answers that other people have already provided but I wanted to somehow summarise things in one place and also have links to the relevant references.

This is what the relevant snippet from my `.vimrc` looks like:

```
    " Cursor appearance
    "
    " See also: [1]'ANSI Control Functions Summary', [2]DECSCUSR, [3]xterm+tmux
    "   entry in terminfo.src.
    " [1] https://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/chapter4.html
    " [2] https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html
    " [3] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/ncurses/master/misc/terminfo.src
    "
    " On:
    " - entered insert mode
    let &t_SI = "^[[5 q^[]12;Magenta\007" " blinking bar (Ss) in magenta (Cs)
    " - entered replace mode
    let &t_SR = "^[[0 q^[]12;Red\007" " blinking block (Ss) in red (Cs)
    " - leaving insert/replace mode
    let &t_EI = "^[[2 q^[]112\007" " terminal power-on style (Se) and colour (Cr)
```

Note: The `'^['` characters are actually one `ESC` (escape sequence) control character.

Answer (score 1):

- Confirming the following's working on **Windows Terminal**, setting the Vim Cursor to IBeam shape in insert mode, underline shape in replace mode and block shape in normal mode.

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>[6 q"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>[4 q"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>[2 q"
```

— Again, from [Change cursor shape in different modes | Vim Tips Wiki | Fandom](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes#For_VTE_compatible_terminals_(urxvt,_st,_xterm,_gnome-terminal_3.x,_Konsole_KDE5_and_others),_wsltty_and_Windows_Terminal)

Answer (score 0):

This works properly on xfce4-terminal:

add following script to your `.vimrc`

```
if has("autocmd")
  au InsertEnter * silent execute "!sed -i.bak -e 's/TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_BLOCK/TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_IBEAM/' ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc"                                                                                          
  au InsertLeave * silent execute "!sed -i.bak -e 's/TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_IBEAM/TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_BLOCK/' ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc"                                                                                          
  au VimLeave * silent execute "!sed -i.bak -e 's/TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_IBEAM/TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_BLOCK/' ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc"  
endif
```

Brief:
As You know xfce4-terminal keeps preferences in `.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` file. The script changes `TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_BLOCK` to `TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_IBEAM` when you're in insert mode, and back to block when you leave insert mode or vim. Feel free to change `IBEAM` to anything you want (`BLOCK`, `IBEAM` and `UNDERLINE` available).

Answer (score -1):

I usually have the current vim mode onto statusline, among other things. If you seek simplicity, you can set [only this information onto the statusline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_statusline_color_to_show_insert_or_normal_mode).

However, usually the really crazy things happen when you have caps lock depressed and are in command mode (since hjkl now are HJKL - just J and K is enough to make you pull your hair out when you don't understand what's happening. Do a `:h J` and `:h K` to see what I mean). Just [beware the caps lock key](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/text_editing/vim.html.en) and you'll be fine most of the time IMO.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @DavidRivers It's an application of the XY problem where the OP was asking for a resolution to his problem (not knowing about being in vim normal mode and wanting the cursor to change to indicate it) but turned out satisfied with an alternative (and IMO not a great) solution (enhancing his statusline with the state)