# Reset or set cursor shape on "VimLeave"

Tags: vim, shapes, text-cursor

I use iTerm2 (Build 1.0.0.20130319) and Vim (bin of MacVim Snapshot 66) on top of OS X 10.7.5 as my CLI editing team.

In iTerm2 I defined to use a non-blinking vertical bar as a cursor shape.
In Vim I defined

```
" Enter insert mode (Cursor shape: vertical bar)
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"

" Leave insert mode (Cursor shape: block)
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

to be able to distinct between insert and normal mode. Basically this works fine. The problem arises when I leave Vim and return to the CLI. What happens is that the cursor does not return in its initial shape (vertical bar). Instead it decides to stay in a block shape.

Could I reset the cursor to it's initial shape or force it to return to be a vertical bar? I Could imagine to trigger an event on e.g. "VimLeave". But I don't know what I could pass as an escape sequence.

Comment: You can refer to the response I did here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58042714/4111295

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a little bit more digging into `:help` I found out that

```
autocmd VimLeave * let &t_me="\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
```

would revert the cursor shape to its initial, or let's say a defined, shape.
That works great so far.

Does anyone know downsides of that approach? Besides `VimLeave` one could also trigger `VimLeavePre` or `QuitPre`.

EDIT:
Even better there's a new plugin available which does exactly what some people are looking for.

https://github.com/jszakmeister/vim-togglecursor

It's a little bit configurable, too:

```
let g:togglecursor_default = "block"
let g:togglecursor_insert = "line"
let g:togglecursor_leave = "line"
let g:togglecursor_disable_tmux = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
autocmd VimLeave * let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
```

Comment: Yes I did. It does not behave as expected. The result is the same as above, as a side effect it doesn't change the shape anymore while switching between normal and insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Iterm with regular vim.  This sets cursor solid on launch vim, blinks on insert mode. And returns to blinking on exit vim.

```
augroup myCmds
au!
autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\e[2 q"
autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\e[1 q"
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method before because I was used to Gvim's cursor style when switching to terminal. But I met the same problem and had no way to fix it.

Finally I have been using changing Cursor colour method. Once I got used to the style, I'm quite happy it and forget the cursor shape at all.

Change Cursor colour method

```
autocmd InsertEnter * set cul
autocmd InsertLeave * set nocul
```

Then set similar but different colour for `Cursor` than `Normal` in the theme if there is no built-in scheme in this theme.

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor

My sum of three methods for identifying insert mode in terminal:
[How to make cursor change in different modes in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217354/how-to-make-cursor-change-in-different-modes-in-vim/15334889#15334889)